# NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 using AFNetworking Sample Code

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using the sample from AFNetworking to get multipart form uploads working.

I have a php app that has a multipart form on a url which is working:

```
digital@nefarious-3 [03:26:21] [~]
-> % curl --form "upload=@Snow.jpg" http://example.dev/api/v1/sendFile
["Successful"]
```

The above is the same endpoint I'm trying to get the AFNetworking request working with. The message is only generated when the file is successfully processed on the api end.

Below is the output of ls -lash on the server:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 290190 Jan 26 15:26 Snow.jpg
```

Below is the example code from the AFNetworking page:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.dev/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"upload" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
    } error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSProgress *progress = nil;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

This errors with the following:

```
2015-01-26 15:16:09.683 digitaltest[8507:241970] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo=0x7fb223551a50 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://example.dev/api/v1/sendFile, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://example.dev/api/v1/sendFile}
```

I can see from custom logging on the PHP side that the iOS app never hits the server. The site is visible on both my local machine and iPad simulator, there are no redirects in place and it does not run over SSL.

I have tried the sample code in both my existing app and a totally brand new app with a simple hello world button without any luck.

How do I get this working?

```
EDIT: As requested here is additional debug:

2015-01-26 20:38:58.211 digitaltest[9340:276782] fileDataURL: file:/Users/digital/Desktop/snow.jpg -- file:///
2015-01-26 20:38:58.223 digitaltest[9340:276782] error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x7ff531757020 {NSFilePath=/file:/Users/digital/Desktop/snow.jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff53177bc90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

Here is output proving the file is there:

```
digital@nefarious-3 [08:39:59] [~]
-> % cd ~/Desktop
digital@nefarious-3 [08:40:05] [~/Desktop]
-> % LL
zsh: command not found: LL
digital@nefarious-3 [08:40:06] [~/Desktop]
-> % ll
total 1272
  0 drwxr-xr-x+  15 digital  staff   510B 26 Jan 20:35 .
  0 drwxr-xr-x+ 113 digital  staff   3.8K 26 Jan 20:40 ..
 24 -rw-r--r--@   1 digital  staff   8.0K 26 Jan 20:35 .DS_Store
  0 -rw-r--r--    1 digital  staff     0B 15 Jul  2013 .localized
  8 -rw-r--r--@   1 digital  staff   2.5K  5 Jan 15:29 Snow[0].jpg
  8 -rw-r--r--@   1 digital  staff   2.5K  5 Jan 15:29 Snow[1].jpg
  8 -rw-r--r--@   1 digital  staff   2.5K  5 Jan 15:29 Snow[2].jpg
  8 -rw-r--r--@   1 digital  staff   2.5K  5 Jan 15:29 Snow[3].jpg
  8 -rw-r--r--@   1 digital  staff   2.5K 26 Jan 20:35 snow.jpg
```

Note the timestamps.

Comment: Look at the request in Charles Proxy, it may never even be sent.

Comment: Have you verified that in the code the file URL is correct, for example checking for it's existence?

Comment: @Zaph url is correct, will take a look at Charles Proxy and see what that says.

Comment: Charles proxy shows that no requests from the app are being sent out, I'm not really sure what's going on here.

Comment: I see the file path: "fileDataURL: file:/Users/digital/Desktop/snow.jpg" but this isnot a valid path for iOS. I see the question is tagged iOS but I see a lot of OS X, it the app OSX or iOS?

Comment: it's for iOS, What's the correct path schema for iOS?

Comment: I encountered a similar problem in my project when testing against a new test server. I extended AFHTTPSessionManager in my code. All I need to get rid of "NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999" is to add a single line like this:

mySessionManager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Due to sandboxing the allowable paths are obtained by using the function `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` with the domain `NSUserDomainMask`.

See [About the iOS File System](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12) for information about available app directories.

Here is an example creating a path to the documents directory for a file named "fileName":

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

Additionally is is allowable to read files from the app bundle.